# parameters for share button not passing when facebook automatically redirects to m.facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile

I have a web based platform that displays a share button on mobile devices. I pass the correct FB-required params so the share opens up with a predefined URL, text and thumbnail image.

When viewing the site on a mobile device [specifically iOS based iphones and ipads], FaceBook automatically detects the fact that it's a mobile device and switches to m.facebook. But in doing so, all the params I sent are lost / ignored.

Does anyone know if this is a FaceBook bug, or is there a new set of params specific to the m.facebook site? If I change the f= line to m.facebook.com it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I send the following share command [again, it works fine on any regular web browser]

```
function doShare() {
    var d = document;
    var f = 'http://www.facebook.com/share';
    var l = d.location, e=encodeURIComponent;
    var p = '.php?src=bm&v=4&i=1262250767&s=100&p[url]=http%3A%2F%2Fqa2%2Eclear%2Dmenu%2Ecom%2FrestHome%2Ephp%3Fr%3D12&p[images][0]=http%3A%2F%2Fqa2%2Eclear%2Dmenu%2Ecom%2Fimages%2FrestLogos%2Flogo%2D12%2Ejpg&p[title]=Clear-Menu:+Novotel+Hotel+--+Netherlands+--+Den+Haag&p[summary]=This+is+marketing+text+that+will+be+included+on+a+FB+share+feed.';
    1;

    try {
        if (!/^(.*\.)?facebook\.[^.]*$/.test(l.host))
            throw(0);
        share_internal_bookmarklet(p)
    }
    catch(z) {
        a=function() {
            if (!window.open(f+'r'+p,'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,resizable=1,width=626,height=436')) {
                l.href=f+'r'+p;
            }
        };
        if (/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            setTimeout(a,0);
        }
        else {
            a();
        }
    }
    void(0);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I modified your code for better readability (You should do this a common practise in your code, if you dont already do it. It HELPS!). Anyway Some suggestions here, as I dont use the facebook API and I cant help directly. But, two things I noticed, what is the `1;` doing in the line after `var p`? And the line `share_internal_bookmarklet(p)` is it supposed to be part of the `if` block? Finally, PLEASE use meaningful variable rather than `f`,`p`,`a`... I will avoid driving other people reading your code from going insane.